# Why must a delegate be public when used as a property?

Tags: c#, properties, delegates

```
class MyClass
{
    **private** delegate void MyDelegate(); //error: MyDelegate is less accessible than property Del
    private MyDelegate del;
    public MyDelegate Del
    {
        get { return this.del; }
        set { this.del = value; }
    }
}
```

Changing to public fixes, but I would like to know why in more detail.

Comment: If the property was *private* then ... read the error message again; it doesn't say "because it's used as a property"; also, all Types used follow these visibility/accessibility rules and not just delegates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MyDelegate` is part of the signature of the public property `Del`.

If something consumes the return value of `Del`, it certainly needs the definition of the type being returned.

In other words, if some other class has an instance of `MyClass` like this:

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
MyDelegate del = myclass.Del;
```

would not be possible unless `MyDelegate` is a type known to that class.

Answer (score 5):

If you define MyDelegate as a private type, how does the consumer of MyClass knows the type of `Del`?  It's like you define a private class and try to use that private class in a public property

Answer (score 1):

`MyDelegate` is the type of the property `Del`. The way `MyClass` would be the type of the class instances. If your class was not public, you wouldnt be able to create instances of the class from outside code.

Same is the case here. Outside code cant access the type `MyDelegate` and wont know what to do with that property.